# Solving a simple first order differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I've got the following first order differential equation that is doing something I can't quite figure out.  The question is to solve:

$$y' = 2x^2y^2$$

Here is my solution:

$$y' \frac{1}{y^2} = 2x^2$$

$$\int \frac{1}{y^2} y' dx = \int 2x^2 dx$$

$$\int \frac{1}{y^2}dy = \int 2x^2 dx$$

$$\ln|y^2| = \frac{2}{3}x^3 + c$$

$$y^2 = e^{\frac{2}{3}x^3 + c} = e^{\frac{2}{3}x^3}.e^c = ce^{\frac{2}{3}x^3}$$

$$y = \sqrt{ce^{\frac{2}{3}x^3}}$$

However, I know from the textbook that this answer is incorrect.  Please help.

Comment: You integrated wrongly with respect to $y$.

Comment: $\int dy 1/y^2=-1/y+C$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\int \frac 1{y^2}\,dy = \int y^{-2} \,dy = -y^{-1} + C$$

So you should obtain $$-\frac 1y = \frac{2}{3}x^3 + c \iff y = -\frac 3{2x^3}\; \text{provided } x\neq 0$$

Comment: Thanks.  I completely overlooked that mistake!

Comment: You're welcome. I've been there!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping $y'$ as $y'$, you should change it into $\frac{dy}{dx}$. Then,$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x^2y^2$$ $$y^2 dy = 2x^2 dx$$ $$\int y^2\, dy = \int2x^2\, dx$$ $$\frac{y^3}{3} = \frac{2}{3}x^3 + C_1$$ $$y = \sqrt[3]{2x^3+C}$$

Comment: Integrate $\frac{dy}{y^2}$ instead of what you have there.